# media query overriding each other?

Tags: html, css

I'm a new beginner to HTML and CSS in general so any advice would be greatly appreciated!
This is the main index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>module 2 assignment</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="module2-solutioncss/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to my first website!</h1>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-4 col-sm-2">lorem ipsum1</div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-4 col-sm-2">lorem ipsum2</div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-4 col-sm-2">lorem ipsum3</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the Css file i created:

```
/*** Base Styles ***/

body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.row>div {
    border:1px solid black;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right:15px;
    padding-left:15px; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
/***desktop devices***/
@media(min-width: 992px) {
    .col-lg-6 {
        width:30%;
        float: left;
    }
}
/***small devices***/
@media (min-width: 1px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    .col-sm-2 {
        width:50%;
        float:none;
    }
}
/***medium devices***/
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .col-md-4 {
        width:45%;
        float: left;
    }
}
```

I can't seem to get the media query from 1px->767px to work which I suspect is due to it being overwritten? I'm trying to create a website where the 3 columns will collapse depending on the width of the device. Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you remove the `min-width: 1px`? It is not needed after, because you don't have to set a specific limit. If you design all the "small" stuff first with the max-width, the next break point can be specified as `max-width: 991px`.

Comment: Also as a hint; try checking out flex-box [nice tutorial here](https://jstutorial.medium.com/the-complete-css-flex-box-tutorial-d17971950bdc)